# Controlling an android device using the emulator

Tags: android, testing, adb, emulation

I'm looking for ways to control an android device using an emulator setup.  The idea is if I plug in a device to the pc, I would like to connect to and control it by using an emulated version of its instance on the pc screen.  For example if I want to manual test I can use a keyboard and mouse to interact with the emulator while watching debug and such but control the actual device in real time.  I've seen some info on controlling an emulator with the device but not vice versa.

I've seen it done with automation ala Robotium and Junit but can it be done just controlling through an emulator tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [MyMobiler](http://www.mymobiler.com/) will work in your case. It streams the screen into the PC where on "emulator like" window you can perform actions like on real phone. And all is happening in real time. Its good tool for videoconferencion.

Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need.  Thanks for the tip.  I just need to understand why it only works partially with my phone now.